# On change event triggers additional event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created some input fields and bound their value to a javascript variable. However, for some reason the drinkInput value is always an empty string. And when the typeInput event is called it's value is correctly printed to the console followed by a blank string which I presume is drinkInput's value.

created here

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="drinkInput" placeholder="Drink Name">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="typeInput" placeholder="Drink Type">
```

and bound here

```
$("#drinkInput").on("change", function() {
    newDrink = $(this).val();
    console.log($(this).val());
});
$("#typeInput").on("change", function() {
    newType = $(this).val();
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

To be clear it seems that I have two different issues. One is that when typeInput's event is triggered it seems that drinkInput's is also. My other issue is that $(this).val() returns an empty string for drinkInput.

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/rtK8Z/

Comment: Huh..stops working when combined with the rest of my code then. It was working before so I'll look into what I changed..

Comment: You probably have errors elsewhere, check the console (F12)

Comment: ...realized that I reused one of the ID names somewhere else. Problem fixed. Can I close my question or do I just leave it up?

Answer (score 0):

It's doing that because you aren't properly closing the tags.

Try this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="drinkInput" placeholder="Drink Name" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="typeInput" placeholder="Drink Type" />
```